# VB.NET How can I popup a game-safe notification?

Tags: vb.net, notifications, toast

How can I, in VB.NET, display a notification on-screen, such as that this will be "game-safe".

Eg: "Theres only 30 minutes left until you will be logged out!".

The notification should not take focus from the game (eg "steal input") and the notification should only be shown for like 5-10 seconds and then disappear by itself.

The notification should also be safe when talking about anticheats, like Punkbuster, VAC and such.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does this mean: _The notification should also be safe when talking about anticheats_? You mean anticheats shouldn't detect or be able to see it?

Comment: No. I mean that it should not use any "suspicious" methods of showing the notification, so it do trigger. Anticheats may see the notification, its fine that it appears on for example EAC screenshots and such, the notification will only contain non-secret information like "Only 30 minutes left until you will be logged off". Its just that it should not be detected as a cheat. For example some overlay menus like XFIRE and such have previously triggered false positives, but anticheat companies have whitelisted XFIRE. Thus my software would then trigger because its not whitelisted.

Comment: What about using a NotifyIcon Balloontip?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about "game safe" as I don't know what those games are looking for to trigger an alert.

What you can do is override ShowWithoutActivation() and return true so that your form does not get focus when shown.  Additionally, you can set the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT extended window style so that all mouse messages literally go right through your form.  Apps underneath won't even know your form is there.  Finally, set Opacity so that you can see through it partially.  Oh...the timer is in there to close it after ten seconds:

```
Public Class frmNotification

    Private WithEvents Tmr As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer

    Private Sub frmNotification_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Opacity = 0.5 ' Make it so you can see thru it partially

        Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None

        ' make it appear in the bottom right of the screen
        Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
        Dim rc As Rectangle = Screen.GetWorkingArea(Me)
        Me.Location = New Point(rc.Right - Me.Width, rc.Bottom - Me.Height)

        Tmr.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds
        Tmr.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Const WS_EX_TRANSPARENT As Integer = &H20

    ' Make all mouse events PASS RIGHT THRU IT:
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property

    ' Show it without activating it:
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property ShowWithoutActivation() As Boolean
        Get
            Return True
        End Get
    End Property


    Private Sub Tmr_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Tmr.Tick
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Didnt work. It does show a click-transparent notification, but the notification still "steals focus" from the game, eg the game goes down to taskbar (same effect as alt-tabbing down the game). Have checked that its not the launch of the application causing it by delaying the notification. And its the showing of the notification that causes it.

Comment: How does your app start?  With a different form?  What were you using to delay?

Comment: No the same form, but on Shown, I check if its first time Shown was ran. Then I hide the form. When its time to show the form, I have both tried me.Show/me.Hide, and the form Me.visible = false / Me.visible = true. AS timer to delay, I use the same timer that is used to hide the form (tmr) but instead I change the interval accordingly. Its upon Visible=true or Show() that the game "alt-tabs" out. Try it yourself on for example CS:GO.